# is it ok to multiply to one a variable to check if is it really a number in php?

Tags: php, variables, numbers, integer

I am doing this to check and already use the variable of type number in php:

```
$myvar = $myvar * 1;
```

with this, I have a number or if $myvar has any other caracter, the result is 0

I wonder if this can somehow trouble me in the future.

for preventing sake, I am using a function that englobes that above code so I can change it if needed. Eg:

```
$myvar = IntOrZero($myvar);
```

so my question if this is a goodway to check and use the number variable?

EDIT:
Using a * 1, I am sure that it will return me a variable of type number.
See:

```
$var = "350";
$num = 120;
// builtin
if (is_numeric($var))
  echo($var - $num);

// multiplying
$var *= 1;
echo($var - $num);
```

While I am not sure if the builtin method would echo what I want, I am sure that the multiplying will.
I kinda don't care if the $var is a number or not, I won't show any message to the user if it is not, I will work with the 0 value if it is not a number. Based on answers, would this be a good way?

```
function IntOrZero($var){
   return is_numeric($var) ? intval($var) : 0;
}
```

thanks,
Joe

Comment: Answer: no.  Use the built in functions.

Comment: Even though everybody below is right in saying there is a proper way of doing this.. at the risk of bring everyone's wrath on me.. sometimes, for small projects where it doesnt really matter, it's just as easy to write $myvar = 0 + $myvar; ( slightly different formulation but same idea)

Comment: @Jonathan `is_numeric($var) ? intval($var) : 0` is equivalent to `intval($var)`, which is equivalent to `(int)$var`. No special function needed.

Comment: @deceze: weirdly, for me, (int)$var is kinda osbcure, I mean, looking at it I am not sure if it will try to cast the string to an int or parse it to an it, see?

Comment: @Jonathan There's no difference. It will turn *anything* into an `int`. If strings contain numbers in any valid expression, they'll be "parsed" into an `int`. These dynamic type conversion rules are at the heart of PHP and you should really get used to them. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting

Comment: @Ben `<wrath>` Please see my updated answer for why it's **never** acceptable to use math operations. `</wrath>`

Comment: @deceze. OK, OK. I did initially say in my comment that I agreed with everybody's answers.. just saying sometimes it doesn't matter that much though.

Comment: @Ben Don't train your bad habits, especially if the "correct way" is not any more complicated. :o)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not a good way, and here's why:

```
$ php -r 'echo array() * 1;'
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in Command line code on line 1
```

To make sure a variable is a number, [cast it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
$integer = (int)$integer;
$float = (float)$float;
```

To *check* whether it's a number or not:

```
is_numeric($var)    // number or string containing any valid numeric expression
ctype_digit($var)   // string containing only digits
is_int($var)        // is of type int
is_float($var)      // is of type float
```

These are all slightly different, depending on what exactly you want to check for. Refer to the documentation:

http://php.net/is_numeric
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php
http://php.net/is_int
http://php.net/is_float

Answer (score 3):

what's wrong with is_int() \ is_numeric() \ ctype_digit() ??

Answer (score 2):

Umm why are you not doing a proper check?

Like:

- [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)
- [is_int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) works too.

I would strongly suggest you use a proper way of checking your value.